# Laravel Mail::queue only works every minute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue

I have a scheduled job that I wish to have run hourly, all this job does is select users whom have not unsubscribed and have not been sent the mailing and then queue the email to be sent.  This is all done on the worker environment in Amazon ElasticBeanstalk and everything is working when it comes to that part.

The job is run hourly and the emails are queued.  However once they are queued they remain in-flight and no email is actually sent out.

If I change the scheduled job to run every minute then everything works fine and the emails are sent, though they are sent twice each for some reason they are being sent.

I am not sure what to look into here because there is nothing in the laravel.log file on the worker instance.  There is also nothing being written to the log file I setup for output from the scheduled command.

This is my code for executing the command.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('ryno:send-email-batch')->hourly()->timezone('America/New_York')->sendOutputTo(storage_path() . '/logs/bulkmail.log');
}
```

This is the code for the command being executed

```
class SendBulkEmailBatch extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'ryno:send-email-batch';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Send a batch of the emails';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $rows = User::where('welcomed', false)->where('unsubscribed', false)->take(600)->get();
        if(count($rows) > 0) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                // send email to the queue to be sent
                Mail::queue('emails.welcome', [], function($message) use($row) {
                    $message->to($row->email);
                    $message->subject('Welcome!');
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each job that is added to the queue ends up in the failed_jobs database table stating that max attempts has been reached.  Any thoughts as to why this may happen?

Comment: Queued emails are sent out via the queue worker. How is that set up?

Comment: I am using supervisor.d to keep the process running and it is running like this  23499 ?        S      0:00 sudo php artisan queue:work sqs --queue=development-queue --tries=5 --sleep=5 --delay=0 --daemon  There is also another process running without sudo according to ps ax | grep queue

Comment: You need to figure out why the queue is failing. If it's making it to the `failed_jobs` table, none of the code/config you've shared is particularly relevant. Run the worker manually and see what errors occur.

Comment: No error is shown or logged to the laravel.log file.  When I run it manually the same thing happens.  The emails are added to the queue and processing fails after a long time elapses.

Comment: however if I have the job run every minute the emails are sent out, it's a bit baffling

Comment: Nothing shows up for an error when i run the queue worker manually either, just sits there waiting to process jobs.  I started the worker, then ran the command and nothing is displaying in the terminal for errors.